# How do I fix blank screen in lightswitch desktop client?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a Visual Studio Lightswitch desktop client. After publishing and starting the application a blank white screen shows up and no menus or screens appear.  This is a new project and it other wise seems to be working fine except that there are "Pending Edit" and "Checked In" bubble messages being generated in the Solution Explorer. There are also red check marks next to the folders in the Solution Explorer.  What can I do to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of repairing .net services in the control panel Programs and Features in this MS TechNet article.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a2650616-1b68-4ae9-9ffd-f4f2a1211254/iis-publication-issues?forum=lightswitch